# How can I create "recursive sql"

Tags: sql, recursion, hsqldb

I want to make "link"

for Example, I have a 5 posts (id: "1", id: "2", id: "3", id: "4", id: "5")

and they have a sequence

> {id:"1", nextId:"2"}, 
>  {id:"2", nextId:"4"} , 
>  {id:"3",
>   nextId:"0"}, 
>  {id:"4", nextId:"3"}, 
>  {id:"5", nextId:"0"},

when I search from "1", I got a result : {id:"1"}, {id:"2"}, {id:"4"}, {id:"3"}
when I search from "5", I got a result : {id:"5"}

How can I find All start with {id:"1"} in ANSI SQL?

```
select s.id, s.nextId from sample s
join sample ns on ns.id = s.nextId
```

It makes from first node to all.

I want to start "{some id}" and I want to use "limit 10"

help me!

Comment: If using Oracle, you have CONNECT BY and START WITH clauses, but they are not ANSI SQL

Comment: now I'm use HSQLDB, but when I finish sample, I have to use MySQL maybe!

Comment: There's a very good example in the HSQLDB documentation http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_with_clause

Comment: If you may have to use MySQL then you'll have to find some other way - amongst things mysql doesn't support is the `WITH` clause. I'd recommend a proper database instead :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have HSQLDB but something like this should do it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE chain(seq, me, next) AS (
  VALUES(0, CAST(null AS int), 1) -- start
  UNION ALL
  SELECT seq + 1, id, nextId
  FROM sample, chain
  WHERE id = next
)
SELECT * FROM chain WHERE seq > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table links (id integer, nextid integer);

insert into links 
values 
(1, 2),
(2, 4),
(3, 0),
(4, 3),
(5, 0);

commit;

with recursive link_tree as (
   select id, nextid
   from links
   where id = 1  -- change this to change your starting node
   union all 
   select c.id, c.nextid
   from links c
     join link_tree p on p.nextid = c.id
)
select *
from link_tree;
```

This is ANSI SQL and works on HSQLDB, PostgreSQL, H2, Firebird, DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle 11.2 and several other engines - just *not* on MySQL (which does not support any of the modern SQL features which are state of the art nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

this works on sql server, maybe it will help you on HSQLDB

on your example, if you inform 1, it would return

```
2->4->3->0
```

its up to you if you want to add the 1 in the begining or maybe remove the 0 from the end

```
CREATE table test_sequence(
id int,
next_id int
)

insert into test_sequence VALUES(1,2)
insert into test_sequence VALUES(2,4)
insert into test_sequence VALUES(3,0)
insert into test_sequence VALUES(4,3)
insert into test_sequence VALUES(5,0)



alter function selectSequence(@id int)
returns varchar(max)
begin
    declare @next varchar(max)
    select @next=next_id from test_sequence WHERE id =@id
    if (@next != '') begin
        return @next +'->'+ dbo.selectSequence(@next)
    end else begin
        select @next=''
    end
    return @next
end

select dbo.selectSequence(1)
```

Comment: A function is an approach you can use, especially in databases that don't support hierarchical queries. However, the code as is will almost certainly not work in HSQLDB.

Comment: SQL Server also supports recursive CTEs and I wouldn't be surprised if that was more efficent than a stored procedure.

Comment: I dont know which one of you downvoted but Colin your code wont work on HSQLDB either so thats not a reason to DV and a_horse_with_no_name I didnt write CTE because its 100% sure it wont work on HSQLDB where function (or any other similar structure) probably are supported, so no reason to DV either

Comment: HSQLDB function syntax is Standard SQL. MySQL function syntax is close. Both are different from MSSQL. HSQLDB has no @ in variable and parameter names.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In the comments, the OP says they may have to use MYSQL. So CTEs are out.

Comment: The function can be rewritten in HSQLDB and MySQL syntax.

Comment: @podiluska: I only saw the HSQLDB tag. And if such a recursive definition is a real requirement OP should really reconsider the decision to use a limited DBMS like MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I entirely agree. Even if they don't want to use CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with recursion is clearly demonstrated by the other answers - the implementation is inconsistent across RDBMS vendors.

Alternatively, you can use the ["nested set"](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html) model, which avoids recursion altogether, and should be easy to construct in a platform-agnostic SQL implementation.

Comment: In this model, an INSERT into the table needs a PROCEDURE definition which requires different syntax for different implementations.

Comment: Not necessarily - that's the example code, but you could implement this in simple SQL statements wrapped in a transaction from the client...