# Firebird (how to find a parent category using SQL)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to create a procedure that takes in a category and gives me back
category parents, like this:

[image]

I have already succeded to create a procedure but it doesn't display data 
in the way I wanted. 
Besides, I believe there's a better way (maybe recursion ?) to accomplish the task, but I don't know how to implement it. Do you have any hints ?

--Database Query--

```
-- Creating Domain Boolean (didn't exist in FireBird) --

CREATE DOMAIN DBOOLEAN
 AS Smallint
 DEFAULT 0
 NOT NULL
 check (Value in (0,1));

-- Creating table --
CREATE TABLE TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT Char(5) NOT NULL,
 NOM_CAT DNOM,
 CUISINE_CAT DBOOLEAN DEFAULT 0,
 FKCATPRINC_CAT Char(5),
 PRIMARY KEY (CODE_CAT)
);

-- Inserted data --
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('B', 'Boissons', 0,null);
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('BS', 'Boissons froides', 0, 'B');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('BV', 'Vins', 0, 'B');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('BVR', 'Vin rouge', 0, 'BV');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('BVB', 'Vin Blanc', 0, 'BV');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('BVROS', 'Vin Rose', 0, 'BV');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('BC', 'Boissons chaudes', 0, 'B');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('V', 'Viande', 1, null);
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('VR', 'Viande Rouge', 1, 'V');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('VB', 'Viande Blanche', 1, 'V');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('P', 'Poisson', 1, null);
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('F', 'Fromage', 1, null);
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('S', 'Sauce', 1, null);
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('D', 'Dessert', 1, null);
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('DC', 'Dessert chaud', 1, 'D');
Insert Into TCATEGORIE
(CODE_CAT, NOM_CAT, CUISINE_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT)
values ('DG', 'Dessert glace', 1, 'D');
```

--My Procedure--

```
    set term^;
create procedure CatParent (choix 
type of column TCATEGORIE.CODE_CAT)
returns (CODE_CAT1 type of column TCATEGORIE.CODE_CAT,
CODE_CAT2 type of column TCATEGORIE.CODE_CAT,
CODE_CAT3 type of column TCATEGORIE.CODE_CAT,
NOM_CAT1 type of column TCATEGORIE.NOM_CAT,
NOM_CAT2 type of column TCATEGORIE.NOM_CAT, 
NOM_CAT3 type of column TCATEGORIE.NOM_CAT )
as 
begin

if(char_length(trim(choix))>=3) 
then 
select c.CODE_CAT, c2.CODE_CAT, c3.CODE_CAT,
c.NOM_CAT, c2.NOM_CAT, c3.NOM_CAT
 from TCATEGORIE c
left join TCATEGORIE c2
on c.CODE_CAT=c2.FKCATPRINC_CAT
left join TCATEGORIE c3
on c2.CODE_CAT=c3.FKCATPRINC_CAT
where c.FKCATPRINC_CAT is null and
c3.code_cat=:choix into :CODE_CAT1, :CODE_CAT2, :CODE_CAT3,
:NOM_CAT1, :NOM_CAT2, :NOM_CAT3;

else if(char_length(trim(choix))=2)
then
select first 1  c.CODE_CAT, c2.CODE_CAT, c.NOM_CAT, c2.NOM_CAT
 from TCATEGORIE c
left join TCATEGORIE c2
on c.CODE_CAT=c2.FKCATPRINC_CAT
left join TCATEGORIE c3
on c2.CODE_CAT=c3.FKCATPRINC_CAT
where c.FKCATPRINC_CAT is null and
c2.code_cat=:choix 
into :CODE_CAT1, :CODE_CAT2, 
:NOM_CAT1, :NOM_CAT2;

else 
select first 1 c.CODE_CAT, c.NOM_CAT
 from TCATEGORIE c
left join TCATEGORIE c2
on c.CODE_CAT=c2.FKCATPRINC_CAT
left join TCATEGORIE c3
on c2.CODE_CAT=c3.FKCATPRINC_CAT
where c.FKCATPRINC_CAT is null and
c.code_cat=:choix into :CODE_CAT1, :NOM_CAT1;


end^
set term;^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure CAT_PARENT (
ICODE_CAT varchar(5))
returns (
CODE_CAT char(20),
NOM_CAT varchar(256),
CUISINE_CAT smallint,
FKCATPRINC_CAT char(20))
as
BEGIN
  FOR
   select
        tcategorie.code_cat,
        tcategorie.nom_cat,
        tcategorie.cuisine_cat,
        tcategorie.fkcatprinc_cat
    from tcategorie
    where 
       (
          (tcategorie.code_cat = :icode_cat)
       )
    INTO :CODE_CAT,
         :NOM_CAT,
         :CUISINE_CAT,
         :FKCATPRINC_CAT
  DO
  BEGIN
   suspend;
    while (:FKCATPRINC_CAT is not null) do
      begin
        execute procedure cat_parent(:FKCATPRINC_CAT)
        returning_values( :CODE_CAT,
           :NOM_CAT,
           :CUISINE_CAT,
           :FKCATPRINC_CAT);
           SUSPEND;
      end
  END
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Edit :

You can also use [CTE(Common Table Expression](http://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html) like this :

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure CAT_PARENT_CTE (
ICODE_CAT varchar(5))
returns (
    CODE_CAT char(20),
    NOM_CAT varchar(256))
as
BEGIN
 for with recursive dept_code
  as (
      select tcategorie.code_cat, tcategorie.nom_cat, tcategorie.fkcatprinc_cat
  from tcategorie
  where (tcategorie.code_cat = :icode_cat)
  union all
  select tcategorie.code_cat, tcategorie.nom_cat, tcategorie.fkcatprinc_cat from dept_code
  inner join tcategorie on tcategorie.code_cat = dept_code.fkcatprinc_cat
 )

  select dept_code.code_cat, dept_code.nom_cat from dept_code
  into :CODE_CAT,:NOM_CAT

  DO
  BEGIN
   suspend;
  END
END^
```

Comment: @SebastianJ You are welcome. I added anoter technique too. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

AS. Proper option would be to avoid using stored procedures and using recursive query.
The recursion depth is hardcoded to be 1024. But for your tree that should be enough.

- [How can I create "recursive sql"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950839/how-can-i-create-recursive-sql)
- http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=recursive

If your tree can grow deeper, then you would have to fall back to SP.

---

And if you want to use SP, then you have to write a `SELECTABLE` procedure.

Instead of `Execute Procedure` (which is one-row action by definition)
you have to try `Select * from CatParent('BVROS')` with a procedure like below.

```
create procedure CatParent (choix 
type of column TCATEGORIE.CODE_CAT)
returns (CODE type of column TCATEGORIE.CODE_CAT,
NOM type of column TCATEGORIE.NOM_CAT
)
as 
DECLARE VARIABLE ParentCode type of column TCATEGORIE.CODE_CAT;
begin
  CODE = :choix;

  While ( 0 = 0 ) DO BEGIN
    if ( CODE is not null ) then LEAVE; -- already traversed to root

    NOM = NULL;
    SELECT NOM_CAT, FKCATPRINC_CAT FROM TCATEGORIE 
      WHERE :CODE = CODE_CAT
      INTO :NOM, :ParentCode;

    if ( :NOM is NULL ) then LEAVE;  
    -- This code does not exists, tree is broken, Error.
    -- Or empty name, Error too.

    SUSPEND;  -- yield results into the "table"

    CODE = :ParentCode;   -- prepare for searching next parent
  END;
end;
```